# LINQ left-join Entity Frame work - Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, left-join

There are simular questions with answers that do not work in my situation.

I'm getting a

> Unable to create a constant value of type '.Model.featureoptions'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Using Entity First, EntityFramework 4.1, MVC3, C# 4.

`vehicles` is a table of vehicle details, `owners` is a table of vehicle owners. `vehicles` and `owners` are inner joined and that works.

`features` table is a list of optional features e.g. sunroof, paint, etc. `featureOptions` is a list of the available options for a feature. e.g. paint could be 'pearlescent', 'matalic' and sunroof could be 'glass pop-up', 'title + slide'.

`vehicleFeatures` is a list of chosen options for a vehicle, for a particulare feature a vehicle can have zero or one record.

In this query `feature1` should be `null` or the chosen value for a feature (i.e. the chosen sunroof option) and `feature2` should be `null` or the chosen value for a different feature (i.e. the chosen paint option)

```
var query = (from v in _entities.vehicles

                 join o
                    in _entities.owners
                    on v.OwnerID equals o.OwnerID

                 // Some more inner joins

                 select new
                 {
                     // <code snipped >
                     // o. fields and v. fields
                     // </ code snipped>

                     feature1 = (from feature1
                                     in _entities.vehiclefeatures
                                     .Where ( f_1 => f_1.VehicleID == v.VehicleID)
                                 join feature1_fo
                                     in _entities.featureoptions
                                 on feature1.FeatureOptionID equals feature1_fo.FeatureOptionID
                                 join feature1_f
                                     in _entities.features
                                     .Where (bt_f => bt_f.CodeEnum==1)
                                 on feature1_fo.FeatureID equals feature1_f.FeatureID
                                 select new featureoptionsDTO () { Option = feature1_fo.Option }
                               ),
                      feature2 = (from feature2
                                         in _entities.vehiclefeatures
                                         .Where(f_2 => f_2.VehicleID == v.VehicleID)
                                      join feature2_fo
                                         in _entities.featureoptions
                                      on feature2.FeatureOptionID equals feature2_fo.FeatureOptionID
                                      join feature2_f
                                          in _entities.features
                                         .Where(feature2_f => feature2_f.CodeEnum == 2)
                                      on feature2_fo.FeatureID equals feature2_f.FeatureID
                                      select new featureoptionsDTO() { Option = feature2_fo.Option }
                                 )
                 }
);

foreach (var vehicle in query)  // Exception here
{
}
```

the

```
feature1 = (from ..
```

and

```
feature2 = (from ..
```

are causing the

> Unable to create a constant value of type '.Model.featureoptions'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I understand that LINQ is trying to create an entity, how can I get it to create an anonymous (or own class) instead?

Comment: it is early days on this project. Considering changing to LinqToSql, database is MySQL though so something like LighSpeed [link](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/LightSpeed) will be needed.

Comment: Don't you have navigation properties in your model? Or why do you write so many explicit joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Entity Framework can't handle select clauses which construct arbitrary types in LINQ to Entities queries. I've tripped over this one a few times myself, and it's quite annoying. It is, however, quite necessary as LINQ to Entities queries are translated into SQL to run on the database, and the database can't handle the construction of .NET objects. It might be nice to be able to do it at the end of the query, but it can certainly never be allowed in the middle.

What I tend to do is write a query which produces exactly the input required to the constructors all in LINQ to Entities, so that it runs on the database. Then call ToEnumerable() on the IQueryable you get from that, which turns it into an IEnumerable, and after that you're in LINQ to Objects so you can do whatever you like in your Select().

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  Not sure how to implement your suggestion though, is it two queries with the left joins in the second hit?

Comment: Better not to call queryable.ToList().Select(...), if you're not going to use that list any other way. You can call queryable.AsEnumerable().Select(...) with roughly the same meaning, except without unnecessarily creating a List object that you're never going to use, and without directly executing the query. If you do need or want to execute the query right now, call ToList() at the very last step: queryable.AsEnumerable().Select(...).ToList().

Comment: or rather, is it two queries with the left joins replaced by second query.

Comment: @hvd you're quite right, I've edited the answer to take that into account. ToEnumerable() is far more appropriate unless you need the list for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a view in the database to do the outer joins and the linq queries the entity assciated with the view.

By doing the left outer in the database means the outer joins are done earlier, possibly making it a bit quicker.  The linq is tidier and just has to do what it needs to, which in this case is filtering.